# Reset animated actor's state in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, animation

I am a complete newbie, making an app in libgdx for which I have this actor that I want to animate on button click. Here is the code for that:

```
public class Boss extends Actor {
    protected Animation animation = null;
    private float stateTime = 0;
    private float width, height;
    private Texture bossTexture;
    private boolean acting, reset;

    public Boss(Animation animation) {
        bossTexture=new Texture("calm.png");
        width=Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        height=Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        acting=false;
        this.animation = animation;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        batch.draw(bossTexture, 200, 100);
        if(acting!=false) {
            TextureRegion currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime);
            batch.draw(currentFrame, 200, 100);
            acting=false;
        }
        if(reset==true){
            batch.draw(bossTexture, 200, 100);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta)
    {
        super.act(delta);
        if(PlayScreen.slapped==true){
            acting=true;
        }
        stateTime+=delta;
    }

    public void reset()
    {
        reset=true;
        stateTime = 0;
    }
}
```

This is the workaround I have for resetting the actor to the default state, but I'm sure there must be another better way. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE : **

I am trying this now.
    package com.storm.game;

```
public class Boss extends Actor {
protected Animation animation = null;
private float stateTime = 0;
private float width, height;
private Texture bossTexture;
private boolean slapping, reset, react;
TextureRegion currentFrame;

public Boss(Animation animation) {
    bossTexture=new Texture("calm.png");
    width=Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    height=Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    slapping=react=reset=false;
    this.animation = animation;
    currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(0);
}

public void setAnimation(Animation anim){
    this.animation=anim;
}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    if(slapping) {
        currentFrame=animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime);
        batch.draw(currentFrame, 200, 100);
        slapping=false;
        //react();
    }
    else{
        batch.draw(currentFrame, 200, 100);
    }
    if(reset){
        currentFrame=animation.getKeyFrame(0);
        batch.draw(currentFrame, 200, 100);
    }
}

@Override
public void act(float delta)
{
    super.act(delta);
    slapping=PlayScreen.slapped;
    stateTime+=delta;
}

public void reset()
{
    reset=true;
    stateTime = 0;
}

}
```

And what happens is the first frame is drawn and that frame is on the top of every other frame that is drawn in the **Slapping** condition.

Which is why, i get a glitched animation showing first frame overlaying every other frame i draw.

This is the playscreen class fom where i draw this actor on screen

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen{

public static boolean slapped, punched;

//init variables
Punish game;

//others
Stage buttonStage;
Sprite bossSprite, backgroundSprite;
Texture bossTexture, backgroundTexture;
TextureRegion bossRegion;
Table buttonTable;
ImageButton slapButton, punchButton;
ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle slapButtonStyle, punchButtonStyle;
TextureAtlas slapButtonAtlas, bossSlapAtlas, punchButtonAtlas, bossPunchAtlas;
Skin slapSkin, punchSkin;
Animation bossSlapAnimation, bossPunchAnimation;
Boss boss;

public PlayScreen(Punish game){
    slapped=punched=false;

    this.game=game;
    buttonStage =new Stage();
    buttonTable=new Table();

    backgroundTexture=new Texture("background.jpg");
    bossTexture=new Texture("calm.png");
    backgroundSprite=new Sprite(backgroundTexture);

    slapButtonAtlas=new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("button.pack"));
    punchButtonAtlas=new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("punchButton.atlas"));
    bossSlapAtlas=new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("boss.pack"));
    bossPunchAtlas=new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("punchAnimation.pack"));

    slapSkin=new Skin();
    punchSkin=new Skin();

    //make buttons
    slapSkin.addRegions(slapButtonAtlas);
    punchSkin.addRegions(punchButtonAtlas);

    //adding style to slap button
    slapButtonStyle=new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
    slapButtonStyle.down=slapSkin.getDrawable("handhit");
    slapButtonStyle.up=slapSkin.getDrawable("hand");
    slapButtonStyle.over=slapSkin.getDrawable("handhit");

    punchButtonStyle=new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
    punchButtonStyle.down=punchSkin.getDrawable("punchHit");
    punchButtonStyle.up=punchSkin.getDrawable("punch");
    punchButtonStyle.over=punchSkin.getDrawable("punchHit");

    //apply style to slap button
    slapButton=new ImageButton(slapButtonStyle);
    punchButton=new ImageButton(punchButtonStyle);


    bossSlapAnimation=new Animation(1/10f, bossSlapAtlas.getRegions());
    bossPunchAnimation=new Animation(1/10f, bossPunchAtlas.getRegions());

    boss=new Boss(bossSlapAnimation);
    boss.setPosition(200,100);

    //Image img=new Image(new Texture("plus.png"));

    //make UI
    buttonTable.left().bottom();
    buttonTable.add(slapButton);
    buttonTable.row();
    buttonTable.add(punchButton);
    buttonTable.add();
    //buttonTable.setBounds(50,50,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    buttonStage.addActor(buttonTable);
    buttonStage.addActor(boss);

    //add listeners
    slapButton.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            slapped=true;
            boss.setAnimation(bossSlapAnimation);
            boss.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
            Gdx.app.log("debug-app", "touched slap");
            boss.reset();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        }
    });

    punchButton.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            punched=true;
            boss.setAnimation(bossPunchAnimation);
            boss.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
            Gdx.app.log("debug-app", "touched punch");
            boss.reset();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        }
    });

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(buttonStage);

    /*bossTexture=new Texture("boss_large.png");
    bossSprite=new Sprite(bossTexture);*/
}

@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    //Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,1,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    game.batch.disableBlending();

    game.batch.begin();
    game.batch.draw(backgroundTexture,0,0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    game.batch.end();


    game.batch.enableBlending();
    game.batch.begin();

    buttonStage.act();
    buttonStage.draw();

    game.batch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    buttonStage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
}
```

Any advises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see big problems in your code since you don't seem to have a problem in the code logic although I'm a little confused in the `draw()` method. Still, I think you can have another small modification in the `draw()` method. Also some minor formatting. Boolean values in comparison statements don't need to be compared explicitly. They can be used as themselves.

```
public class Boss extends Actor {
    protected Animation animation = null;
    private float stateTime = 0;
    private float width, height;
    private Texture bossTexture;
    private boolean acting, reset;

    public Boss(Animation animation) {
        bossTexture=new Texture("calm.png");
        width=Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        height=Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        acting=false;
        this.animation = animation;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        if(acting) {
            TextureRegion currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime);
            batch.draw(currentFrame, 200, 100);
            acting=false;
        } else { // so that it don't have to draw every frame but still keeps the logic
            batch.draw(bossTexture, 200, 100);
        }
        if(reset){
            batch.draw(bossTexture, 200, 100);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta)
    {
        super.act(delta);
        acting = PlayScreen.slapped;
        stateTime+=delta;
    }

    public void reset()
    {
        reset=true;
        stateTime = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the formatting comments, looks much better now, although the issue with using this method is, i would have to add more animation for the same actor, for which, more booleans will be added, handling which doesnt seem possible to me.

Comment: How is that a problem? If you have other animations, just assign them to the `animation` field when needed. The `draw()` method will render whatever texture it gets.

Comment: I initialize Boss class before act or draw is called, so i wouldn't know which animation to send. @WeirdElfB0y

Comment: Oh, okay. But then if you can make a public setter method for the animation, you can change it after you call Boss.

Comment: Oh yes, why didn't i think of that. Thank u so much, i'll implement it, and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I had the 'same' problem after fading a non-looping actor.
I changed the animation to loop and added

```
myActor.addAction(
  Actions.sequence(
    Actions.delay((frameDuration*framesAnimated), Actions.removeActor())));
```

this removes the actor after one loop and allows it to be reused